# Strange interaction between Module and ListPlot

Tags: bugs, scoping, predictive-interface

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.1**

---

Why is the variable **a** ending up assigned to {1,2,3} after executing

```
Module[{a},
a=Range[3];
ListPlot[a]
]
```

Comment: What version are you using?  I've tried this on Windows M9 and M10 and don't see the issue.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10 in OS X Yosemite.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in M10.0.1.0 on OS X 10.9.5

Comment: I can reproduce this on "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014)" using OS X Yosemite. Must be a platform-specific bug. You should report it to WRI.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It's not.  One more problem caused by the Suggestions Bar.

Answer (score 6):

This is yet another bug caused by the Suggestions Bar.

Workaround:

- Go to Preferences... -> Interface, and uncheck "Show Suggestions Bar after last output".

I can reproduce it on OS X, Mathematica 10.0.2, but *not* in version 9.0.1.

---

Whenever I see that some people can reproduce a bug, some can't, I turn on the Suggestion Bar and check if it's the culprit.  Very often it is.  That's why I keep it off.

Comment: A-ha! I turned off the Suggestions Bar long ago as soon as I found out that I could.  I did not realize it also had such a side effect.  Its popping in and out of existence is enough of a headache for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

Very strange!

If you put an "a" after it works as expected:

```
Module[{a}, a = Range[3];
 ListPlot[a]]
a
```

It also works if you suppress the `Module`'s output (but not `ListPlot`'s):

```
Module[{a}, a = Range[3];
  Print@ListPlot[a]];
```

Comment: This is yet another symptom of Sugestions Bar caused trouble.  Putting the `a` at the end prevents the Suggestions Bar from messing with the previous output.